# Regular expression for these 2 rules

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have written this regular expression to validate the 2 rules.

**Rule 1 :**

number should be either 10-11 characters with postion 1-9 as numeric and 10 alpha and 11 can be either'

**Rule 2 :**

number should be between 7 to 12 characters where position one should be alpha; position 2 to 4 can be either and position 5 to 12 can be either'

```
^{7,12}[1-9]{2,12}[A-Z0-9]{1,12}'
```

is this correct ?

Comment: Rule 1: `\d{9}[a-zA-Z]\w?`, Rule 2: `[a-zA-Z]\w{6,11}`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff `\w` = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: I need both the rules in one regular expression

Comment: *position 2 to 4 can be either and position 5 to 12 can be either* is somehow confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^(\d{9}[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]?|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{6,11})$
```

[Live Example](http://rubular.com/r/ulAbjjuNvp)

Comment: You need to group your alternation, this way `^` belongs to the first alternative and `$` to the second.

Comment: You can't insert classes into sets such as `[a-zA-Z\d]`

Comment: so guys which one do i use?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, I checked `\d` works on rubular.com but I have changed `\d` to `0-9` now. Can you please explain what you want to highlight ?

Comment: Why Ruby?  OP wants Oracle regex.

Comment: @akram, post some sample data it will help us to troubleshoot the issue you are facing.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, you can put predefined classes (when they are supported at all) in your own classes in all languages I know (e.g. `[\s\d,.-]`). Is Oracle/sql different here?

Comment: this would be valid now, 528846615A invalid would be something like this ME225019

Comment: @stema - Probably, you know not so many regex flavors/languages.

Comment: @Neverhopeless, I tried yours it seems to work. but then Stema commented that you missed something. so ^(\d{9}[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]?|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{6,11})$ is the final one ?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Perl, .net, Java, Javascript, Ruby, Python, PCRE. I think I know a lot about regex, but could be that Oracle/SQL is doing something special.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff [check Shorthand Character Classes on regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand)

Comment: @stema - Obviously, that site doesn't cover all regex flavors.  So, it would be wise to learn Oracle regex before answering Oracle regex questions.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, I haven't answered that question, I asked you a question since I am interested in this topic. Btw. I searched the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25518/adfns_regexp.htm#CHDJGBGG) and it seems that Oracle is supporting "only" PCRE ERE (listed on that site) and made some extensions on its own. From there it supports `\d` and to my opinion if this shorthand class is not working inside a character class, I would consider it a bug, since this is standard behaviour everywhere else. I haven't seen this limitation being mentioned in the doc.

Comment: @akram, yes this is the final one i want to propose. Actually i missed the outer braces and because of this you won't get a group as a result. So its a final one.

Comment: @stema - Yes, all that you can't understand in Oracle (the language you doesn't know) is a bug, surely.  LOL.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, I agreed with Stema, these are standard things I have used in my expression and i have also find them common in many regex engines. Please instead of `LOL` guide me (with some doc ref) to learn REGEX IN ORACLE that support your argument.

Comment: @NeverHopeless - Oracle docs never claimed full support of Perl regex.  I don't know why stema thinks Oracle MUST support all features from other regex flavours.

Answer (score 3):

First you want to allow both rules and ignore case `/i`:

```
^(rule1|rule2)$/i
```

first rule:

```
\d{9}     # 9 digits
[a-z]     # one alpha
[0-9a-z]?  # last is optional and can be either
```

second rule:

```
[a-z]         # position one
[0-9a-z]{6,11} # remaining with value either, 6 to 11 characters
```

result:

```
^(\d{9}[a-z][0-9a-z]?|[a-z][0-9a-z]{6,11})$/i
```

Comment: Hoffman i tried this and it's not working, I have data which doesn't meet those rules. So i've written a query to display the numbers which do not meet the regexp and i dont see those numbers.

Comment: select a.mycolumn from mytable a where a.mycolumn not in
(select a.mycolumn from mytable2 a where 
regexp_like (a.mycolumn,'^(\d{9}[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]?|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{6,11})$')

Comment: No, I mean an entry that is (not) matched that should (not)

Comment: this is one of the exampple ME225018

Comment: you probably didn't use the case modifier correctly? For me preg_match("/^(\d{9}[a-z][0-9a-z]?|[a-z][0-9a-z]{6,11})$/i", "ME225018")) == 1

Comment: I just checked regexp_like-documentation, you definitively need 'i' as third parameter to switch to case-insensitive.

Comment: M sorry, I did use ur exp its just that i posted the wrong one! I dont see the data.